# Cannot call an abstract base member

Tags: c#, asp.net, spread

I'm attempting to create a custom cell type for Spread.NET. The error I get is:

> Cannot call an abstract base member:
> 'FarPoint.Web.Spread.BaseCellType.PaintCell(string,
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell, FarPoint.Web.Spread.Appearance,
> FarPoint.Web.Spread.Inset, object, bool)'

Here's the code:

```
[Serializable()]
public class BarcodeCellType : FarPoint.Web.Spread.BaseCellType
{
    public override Control PaintCell(string id, TableCell parent, Appearance style, Inset margin, object value, bool upperLevel)
    {
        parent.Attributes.Add("FpCellType", "BarcodeCellType");

        if (value != null)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = GenerateBarCode(value.ToString());
                var img = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
                value = img;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                value = ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        return base.PaintCell(id, parent, style, margin, value, upperLevel); //ERROR HERE
    }

    private MemoryStream GenerateBarCode(string codeInfo)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BarCodeBuilder bb = new BarCodeBuilder();
            bb.CodeText = codeInfo;
            bb.SymbologyType = Symbology.Code128;
            bb.BarCodeImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the base method virtual and have the same signature as your override?

Comment: Just a heads up, you have a memory leak.  Your MemoryStream and Bitmap instances should be cleaned up by calling Dispose() after you are done with them or wrapping them in "using" blocks

Comment: Hi mjmarsh - I updated my code..do you mean doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your abstract class "FarPoint.Web.Spread.BaseCellType" you probably defined the PaintCell method as abstract and an abstract method declaration introduces a new virtual method but does not provide an implementation of that method. Instead, non-abstract derived classes ("BarcodeCellType") are required to provide their own implementation by overriding that method. Because an abstract method provides no actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`PaintCell` is declared `abstract` not `virtual` so you can't do the `base.PaintCell` call. It is up to your code to create the `Control` object and return it.

If you don't want to be creating the `Control` you may want to inherit from a more derived class than `BaseCellType` and overriding that derived classes `PaintCell` method.

Answer (score 1):

The base member is abstract, meaning there's no implementation.  Removing the call to `base.PaintCell` will allow the code to *compile*, but I'm not sure that will get the code you have to *work*.

Comment: It won't compile as he is relying on the method to create the `Control` that will be returned from his override, I think he is in for a lot of work ahead of him to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

[An abstract method doesn't come with an implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435.aspx); a subclass must provide an implementation, which is exactly what you're doing.

Just omit the call.

Answer (score -1):

You can't call abstract methods. It needs to be defined in the derived class.